# I need to combine Pages Listing and Main Menu from frontend in Wordpress

Tags: plugin-development

I have created custom functionality for changing order of Pages from frontend programmatically now I need to combine that functionality with main menu , I can create menu-items into submenu-items and vice-versa as drag and drop just as we are having default functionality in Menus in admin side as in frontend side.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have created one custom sidebar where pages are listed with drag and drop functionality which updates the order in wp-admin side programmatically from frontend side. Now i want to create functionality which displays that listing as menu-item and submenu-item and vice-versa just as we have in Menus in wp-admin side in frontend side. ie:- I need (Drag and Drop for changing order of Pages + default menu-item/submenu-item functionality which is available in Menus section in wp-admin side that i need it in frontend side)